# Regex to detect repetitions of an speficif character

Tags: python, regex

There's being a while since I last used regex...
I have a string of 0s and 1s:

```
0010001110011000
```

And I have to split it by blocks of 1 (2 or more consecutive 1s):

```
001000 # These are the blocks what matters to me
00
000
```

I'm wondering how to do that.

I was trying something like this, in Python:

```
l = re.compile("([1])\1+").split(s)
```

But it is not right.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
re.split(r'1{2,}', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BqABHp/1). Here, `1{2,}` matches 2 or more (due to the [limiting quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{2,}`) `1` digits.

If the `1`s may appear at the beginning, you will need to remove empty elements, say, with `filter(None, result)`.

See a [Python demo](http://ideone.com/hsaLe1).

Comment: Is this equivalent to "11+"?

Comment: Yes, `1{2,}` mean 2 or more `1`s.